# My app is taking phantom space on my iPad's storage

Tags: ios, memory, filesystems, diskspace

So, I'm working on an app for iPad that involves drawing.
It stores files in two places: the userDocument :

```
FileManager.default.url( for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true )
```

and the appSupportFolder:

```
FileManager.default.url( for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true )
```

What happens now is, iOS tells me my app is taking up 18GB of space on disk, even though i cleared all the document directory (using the finder, as this one is visible) and the support folder :

```
if  let suppPath = try? FileManager.default.url( for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true ),
    let URLs = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory( atPath: suppPath.path )
{
    for url in URLs
    {
        let completePath = suppPath.appendingPathComponent( url )
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem( at: completePath )
    }
}
```

After this, i don't even know how to check the content of this folder, but i ran this :

```
func ScanDir( url: URL, depth: Int )
{
    var string = ""
    for _ in 0 ..< depth
    {
        string += "----"
    }

    string += "\(url.lastPathComponent)"
    debugPrint( string )

    if let URLs = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory( atPath: url.path )
    {
        for urlstring in URLs
        {
            ScanDir( url: url.appendingPathComponent( urlstring ), depth: depth+1 )
        }
    }
}
```

The result from the scan is then

```
"Application Support"
```

When before, i could see all my projects, exported files, brushes etc...
So it seemed to have worked.
But still, the app is up to 18GB.

Then i can uninstall it, but then as soon as I rebuild the app, it goes back.
I'm so confused right now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as it turns out, iOS automatically puts anything deleted from .documentDirectory in a hidden trash within that same folder.

So all images that i stored on .documentDirectory and then deleted, went in a .trash folder, that i have no idea how to see on the iPad, it just wouldn't let me know that there was this going on. I guess i'm not very familiar with iStuff yet.

So i had to run my cleaning sequence over this folder to get rid of it ..